# HP EliteBook 8440p screen flickers after blank screen (nvidia)

Tags: nvidia, screen, hp, flicker

When my screen turns blank after 10 min or after locking the screen and I begin using the laptop again, the screen is flickering.

It looks as if every second line of pixels is blinking and the flickering is mainly present in the upper part of the screen.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with the latest binary Nvidia drivers (current-updates).
lshw | grep VGA tells me:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)

The problem doesn’t occur after sleeping or on an external display. I used Kubuntu 11.10 before, where the problem didn’t occur either.

Is there anything I can do except waiting for new drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same machine and I had the same issue on Windows 7 and now Windows 8.

I updated the Nvidia drivers twice and the issue persisted. I don't think its OS or driver related but rather that the screen itself or video card may be failing.

Thankfully, the laptop is still under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend turning dithering off (disabled) using nvidia-settings. If it improves, update /etc/X11/xorg.conf to add the following in the "Screen" Section and restart X/or reboot.

Option "FlatPanelProperties" "Dithering=Disabled"

Good luck.